# Overwrite attribute value on where - Rails 5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Hello I need to do like Devise in my own implementation and query `User.where(:password => 'password')` but password is encrypted and salted. What would be the "rail" way of overwriting this behaivour? I tried with an attr_writter

```
def password=(pass)
   super(hashpassword(pass))
end
```

But no success, I still see `SELECT  'users'.* FROM 'users' WHERE 'users'.'password' = 'non-salted-password' LIMIT 11`

Any suggestion? thank you.

**Important**

I'm not using devise.

**About the solution**

The approved solution was to use the native "authenticate" method, I had to change my password field in the database to password_digest and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an [authenticate](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/InstanceMethodsOnActivation/authenticate) method available for this. This works with [has_secure_password](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_secure_password).

`authenticate` is used as follows:

```
user = User.new(password: 'hash-of-the-password')
user.save
user.authenticate('not-the-password')      # => false
user.authenticate('password') # => user
```

`has_secure_password` requires a column called `password_digest` (though you might be able to override this), which is filled with a hash after someone signs up with a password / password confirmation.

Hope that helps - let me know if you need anything more or have any questions.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure that's what you're looking for?? If not, let me know and I'll delete this.

Comment: That's straight from ActiveModel :) You'll be able to grab it in Rails - works with `has_secure_password`, which I'll add to my answer :)

Comment: Welcome - happy to help!